# How to solve missing FROM clause in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've created the following tables and types in PosgreSQL.

```
CREATE TYPE WordTy AS (
 id VARCHAR(20)  
);

CREATE TYPE PageTy AS (
  url VARCHAR(100),
  title VARCHAR(60),
  data_lettura DATE
);

CREATE TYPE OccurrenceTy AS (
  word WordTy,
  page PageTy,
  occurrences_number INTEGER
  );

CREATE TABLE Page OF PageTy(PRIMARY KEY(url));

CREATE TABLE Word OF WordTy(PRIMARY KEY(id));

CREATE TABLE Occurrence OF OccurenceTY;
```

I want to know all the pages that contain a given word.
When I run this query:

```
SELECT occ.page.title as page_title, occ.page.url as url_page FROM 
  Occurrence occ WHERE occ.id=1
```

The output is:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "page"
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

See [Accessing Composite Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-ACCESSING).

You need to use brackets: `(occ.page).title`.

---

You also have some typos in your SQL:

`CREATE TABLE Occurrence OF OccurenceTY;`

should be

`CREATE TABLE Occurrence OF OccurrenceTy;`

`FROM Occurrences occ`

should be

`FROM Occurrence occ`

and

`WHERE occ.id=1`

should be

`WHERE (occ.word).id='1'`

---

Final query:

```
SELECT (occ.page).title as page_title, (occ.page).url as url_page FROM 
  Occurrence occ WHERE (occ.word).id='1'
```